# How to write prolog program and queries

Tags: prolog

Write Prolog program for following. I wrote every thing and I need to know final two are correct or not which I wrote.

```
1. saman likes maths.
2. saman likes science.
3. udara likes maths.
4. fazal likes science.
5. fazal likes music.
6. geetha likes history.
7. geetha likes science.
8. geetha likes music.
9. those who like maths and science will follow engineering for advance level.
10. those who likes history or music will follow art for advance level.
```

Is this correct for final two?

```
student(X):- like(X,maths_and_science),follow(X,engineering).
student(X):- likes(X,history_or_music), follow(X,art).
```

2. I don't know how to write a Prolog queries for following.

   ```
   1) Does saman like maths or music?

   2) Who likes science and music?

   3) who will do engineering?
   ```

Please help me.

Comment: I think *before* you implement the rules, you first need to define the *predicates* and *functors* with the corresponding *semantics*. But the last two are - as far as I can see - not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 9. those who like maths and science will follow engineering for advance level.
> 10. those who likes history or music will follow art for advance level.
>
> Is this correct for final two?

No. It could be:

```erlang
will_follow(Student, engineering) :-
    likes(Student, maths),
    likes(Student, science).

will_follow(Student, art) :-
    likes(Student, history)  ;
    likes(Student, music).
```

> 1) Does saman like maths or music?

```erlang
likes(saman, art) ; likes(saman, music).     % intentionally incorrect
```

> 2) Who likes science and music?

```erlang
likes( Who, science) , likes( Who, maths).   % intentionally incorrect
```

> 3) who will do engineering?

```erlang
will_follow( Who, arts ).                    % intentionally incorrect
```

Since this looks like an assignment, I've intentionally used wrong names here and there. You will have to correct those.

Comment: Thanks for your kindly help. It has most useful for my future works.